# aggregate in r is removing 0 count in table. How to make it show?

Tags: r, aggregate, summarize

I'm trying to generate a table with `aggregate` for further processing using `FUN` argument in `aggregate`. Here's my code

```
var <- c(1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)

aggregate(var, list(group), FUN = table)
```

but, the result is showing up like this where group 4 has no value for the second level (0 or 1)

```
  Group.1      x
1       1  61, 3
2       2 112, 3
3       3  30, 2
4       4     21
```

The desired result should be like this:

```
  Group.1  x.0  x.1
1       1  61   3
2       2 112   3
3       3  30   2
4       4  21   0
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We need to create the 'var' as `factor` with `levels` specified as 0 and 1.  This would make sure that if the count is 0 for a particular column to show up as 0

```
var <- factor(var, levels = 0:1)
out <- aggregate(var, list(group), FUN = table)
out
#   Group.1 x.0 x.1
#1       1  29  21
#2       2  29  21
#3       3  23  27
#4       4   0  50
```

Or use the `formula` method

```
out <- aggregate(var ~ group, FUN = table)
```

Note that these will result in a `matrix` 'x' with two columns.  Inorder to have as regular `data.frame` columns

```
do.call(data.frame, out)
```

---

Or in case, for a change, we can also get the `sum` of 1s and then `reshape`

```
reshape(aggregate(cbind(n = rep(1, length(group))) ~ 
  group+ var, FUN = sum), idvar = 'group', direction = 'wide', timevar = 'var')
```

---

If we are using `tidyverse`, instead of doing any change in the `class` i.e. converting to `factor`, do a `count` using both the variables and then `spread` it to 'wide' format

```
library(tidyverse)
tibble(var, group) %>% 
    count(var, group) %>%
    spread(var, n, fill = 0)
# A tibble: 4 x 3
#  group   `0`   `1`
#  <int> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1    29    21
#2     2    29    21
#3     3    23    27
#4     4     0    50
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
var <- sample(0:1, 200, replace = TRUE)
var[151:200] <- 1
group <- rep(1:4, each = 50)
```